# Обработка нажатия кнопки внутри item recycler и взаимодействие с presenter

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, adapter, mvp

Добрый день такой вопрос. Есть recyclerview, в каждом item которого есть ImageButton который имеет свою обработку нажатия отличную от обработку нажатия на элемента RecyclerView, если быть конкретнее то должен запускать и взаимодействовать с service"ом. При создании приложения придерживаюсь MVP. Вопрос такой где лучше запускать сервис. Передавать каким либо образом в адаптер презентер и организовывать обработку нажатия  в презентере или взаимодействовать с сервисом из адаптера. Заранее извиняюсь, если вопрос глупый или за какие либо неточности.

Comment: ViewHolder должен только отвечать за view. Все тяжелые работы он должен делегировать. Создайте interface листенера(+ методы registerListener/unregisterListener) у адаптера. А дальше, на подобие, OnClickListener